# truth value of the following statement: $\exists x\forall y\neq0(xy=1)$

Tags: propositional-calculus, quantifiers

I'm trying to figure out the truth value of the statement, and the correct way to read it. I'm reading it as :" there exists $x$, such that for all values of $y$ not equal to $0$, $xy=1$". So I think its false. Can someone please provide feedback

Comment: Your interpretation looks correct to me, and I agree its false (assuming $y\in\mathbb{R}$ or something else sensible, as pointed out by @Shaun). Also, use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to make your maths look pretty (I've edited it in, so you can see what it looks like).

Comment: In which structure are you working? The answer is totally depending on that question.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net is right. In binary ($U=\{0,1\}$ with the usual operations) it would work, but on the real numbers it doesn't (it is true that every non-zero real number has an inverse but its inverse isn't the same for all real numbers). The formula is well defined (although it is abbreviated), but its truth value depends on the theory we are working on.

Answer (score 2):

The symbols $\exists$ and $\forall$ need to have a domain, and presumably it is implicit in the problem you are looking at. If this domain is nice then your interpretation is correct. For example,
$$\exists x\in\mathbb{R}\:\forall y\in\mathbb{R}\:(xy=1)$$
is a false statement (as $x$ is fixed so there is at most one $y\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $xy=1$, namely $1/x$).

On the other hand,
$$\exists x\in\{1\}\:\forall y\in\{1\}\setminus\{0\}\:(xy=1)$$
is a true statement.

---

Finally, note that swapping the quantifiers produces a true statement (assuming a nice domain):
$$\forall x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}\:\exists y\in\mathbb{R}\:(xy=1)$$